# convert json to datatable using rjsonio

Tags: json, r, jsonlite

I have properly formatted JSON fetched through a standard API.

API Basically returns an array of JSON objects each time I fetch data.

LIke this:

```
[
{}, 
{}, 
{}
]
```

I have used JSON editor to check structure of JSON data and that looks perfect. 
I need to convert it to CSV so tried this:

```
freshDeskRaw <- fromJSON(freshDeskTickets)
tmp <- lapply(freshDeskRaw , function(u) 
  lapply(u, function(x) if(is.null(x)) NA else x)
)
tmp <- lapply( tmp, as.data.frame)
tmp <- do.call( rbind, tmp )
```

At

```
tmp <- lapply( tmp, as.data.frame)
```

, I get an error:

> tmp <- lapply( tmp, as.data.frame)
>   Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

how do I fix this? what looks wrong? I have tried to use

`as.data.frame(tmp)` as well but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the JSON above produces empty lists and

```
is.null(list())
# [1] FALSE
```

Try

```
is.null(x) || (is.list(x) && length(x) == 0)
```